# Microdata itemprop causes W3C validator error

Tags: w3c-validation, microdata, xhtml-1.0-strict

After adding Microdata to my pages, I got many errors from W3C validator complaining the `itemprop`:

> there is no attribute "`itemprop`"

From code like this:

```
<p itemprop="description">...</p>
```

This is my DOCTYPE and `html` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

How to fix the validator errors?

p.s. Previously I have the validator error for `itemscope` as well. But after I changed it to `itemscope="itemscope"` then the error is fixed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Documents with [HTML 5](http://www.HTML-5.com/) plus Microdata used to validate successfully but because of [Bug #14020](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14020) the validator has become more strict on declaring documents as "valid".  Your document is valid HTML 5 + Microdata, but is not strictly an HTML 5-only document.

You can use http://Validator.nu/ to validate HTML 5 + Microdata.

The site linked to in Fabian's answer is *not* the *W3C* site he mentions, so I wouldn't trust that as much for HTML 5 as I might have for earlier (pre-2000) [versions of HTML](http://www.HTML-5.com/html-versions-and-history.html#html-versions).

The reason you had to change itemscope to itemscope="itemscope" is that previous browsers and specifications have defined incompatible interpretations (sometimes true, sometimes false) of code such as itemscope (no value), itemscope="" (an empty string is interpreted as false by XPath) and itemscope="false" (any non-empty string sometimes interpreted as true). Thus the statement in the spec that "The values 'true' and 'false' are not allowed on boolean attributes." However, "true" and "false" *can* appear in certain attribute values because they *are* allowed on enumerated attributes such as [draggable](http://www.HTML-5.com/attributes/draggable-attribute.html). See bullet #4 regarding [coding boolean values](http://www.HTML-5.com/tutorials/converting-to-html-5.html).

The workarounds (elsewhere) to insert invalid code with scripting may hide that code from the validator, but it won't create a document that is any more valid than using static HTML code because the HTML 5 specification is defined in terms of the internal document model, not the external representation. See [HTML 5 Specifications focus on the DOM](http://www.HTML-5.com/changes/#changes).

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is what I did to make this work with the Validator:

Referring to this page: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110525/

I enclosed the main  in my page (the "wrapper" if you will) with the following:

```
<div id="layout" itemscope>
```

If you have itemscope in the div tag for your page or for the div containing microdata, then the W3C Validtor will like it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The DOCTYPE needs to be HTML5 for microdata to validate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
.....
```

It will work with paragraph tag:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110525/

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to remove this tag you can do so by removing tag from file which is located in main root folder

"**wp-includes/general-template.php**" at **891 line**

you can just remove extra tag.